# numpy genfromtxt IndexError when using comments

Tags: python, numpy, comments, genfromtxt

I'm trying to import data from a text file into python using genfromtxt().
The code I have currently is

```
lowResOmni = np.genfromtxt('omni low res 7-14 to 7-18.txt', dtype=[('year', int), ('SOY', float)
                                                             , ('B', float), ('Bx', float), ('By', float), ('Bz', float)
                                                             , ('plasmaTemp', float), ('ionDensity', float), ('plasmaSpeed', float), ('plasmaPressure', float)
                                                             , ('pFlux1', float), ('pFlux2', float), ('pFlux4', float), ('pFlux10', float)
                                                             , ('DST', int), ('AL', int), ('AU', int)]
                                            , comments="#", skip_header=2, usemask=True
                                            , missing_values={0:'', 1:''
                                                            , 2:999.9, 3:999.9, 4:999.9, 5:999.9
                                                            , 6:9999999., 7:999.9, 8:9999., 9:99.99
                                                            , 10:999999.99, 11:99999.99, 12:99999.99, 13:99999.99
                                                            , 14:99999, 15:99999, 16:99999})
```

which gives me an `IndexError: list index out of range` whenever the .txt file has lines starting with # at the beginning. I have tried this exact code on a .txt file with the commented lines removed and it works fine, but I would rather not have two separate files for the data and comments.

For example

```
TIME_AT_CENTER_OF_HOUR 1AU_IP_MAG_AVG_B 1AU_IP_BX,_GSE 1AU_IP_BY,_GSM 1AU_IP_BZ,_GSM 1AU_IP_PLASMA_TEMP 1AU_IP_N_(ION) 1AU_IP_PLASMA_SPEED 1AU_IP_FLOW_PRESSURE 1AU_PROTONS>1_MEV 1AU_PROTONS>2_MEV 1AU_PROTONS>4_MEV 1AU_PROTONS>10_MEV 1-H_DST 1-H_AL-INDEX AU-INDEX
Year____Secs-of-year                 nT             nT             nT             nT              Deg_K         Per_cc                Km/s                  nPa   1/(SQcm-ster-s)   1/(SQcm-ster-s)   1/(SQcm-ster-s)    1/(SQcm-ster-s)      nT           nT       nT
  2000 16849800.000000          5.50000       -4.90000      -0.800000       -1.20000            321609.        2.80000             606.000              1.92000           614.000           156.000           25.5000            1.87000     -29         -279      234
  2000 16853400.000000          4.30000       -2.90000       -2.90000       0.400000            200127.        3.40000             611.000              2.42000           625.000           159.000           26.2000            1.91000     -20         -245      164
  2000 16857000.000000          3.90000       -2.10000       -2.50000        1.40000            174932.        3.70000             615.000              2.70000           549.000           142.000           23.2000            1.79000     -12         -264      113
  2000 16860600.000000          3.60000       -1.30000       -2.40000       0.600000            148701.        3.40000             616.000              2.61000           492.000           125.000           20.5000            1.62000     -14         -155      109
  2000 16864200.000000          4.10000       -1.00000       -2.20000       0.500000            116372.        2.70000             614.000              2.20000           485.000           124.000           20.5000            1.73000     -20         -140       89
  2000 16867800.000000          4.30000       -1.40000       -1.00000       -3.60000            96452.0        2.50000             607.000              1.91000           465.000           119.000           19.5000            1.63000     -19         -275      240
#  
# Key Parameter and Survey data (labels K0,K1,K2) are preliminary browse data.
# Generated by CDAWeb on: Mon Nov 15 15:35:02 2021
```

works fine, but

```
# now we have an error for some reason
TIME_AT_CENTER_OF_HOUR 1AU_IP_MAG_AVG_B 1AU_IP_BX,_GSE 1AU_IP_BY,_GSM 1AU_IP_BZ,_GSM 1AU_IP_PLASMA_TEMP 1AU_IP_N_(ION) 1AU_IP_PLASMA_SPEED 1AU_IP_FLOW_PRESSURE 1AU_PROTONS>1_MEV 1AU_PROTONS>2_MEV 1AU_PROTONS>4_MEV 1AU_PROTONS>10_MEV 1-H_DST 1-H_AL-INDEX AU-INDEX
Year____Secs-of-year                 nT             nT             nT             nT              Deg_K         Per_cc                Km/s                  nPa   1/(SQcm-ster-s)   1/(SQcm-ster-s)   1/(SQcm-ster-s)    1/(SQcm-ster-s)      nT           nT       nT
  2000 16849800.000000          5.50000       -4.90000      -0.800000       -1.20000            321609.        2.80000             606.000              1.92000           614.000           156.000           25.5000            1.87000     -29         -279      234
  2000 16853400.000000          4.30000       -2.90000       -2.90000       0.400000            200127.        3.40000             611.000              2.42000           625.000           159.000           26.2000            1.91000     -20         -245      164
  2000 16857000.000000          3.90000       -2.10000       -2.50000        1.40000            174932.        3.70000             615.000              2.70000           549.000           142.000           23.2000            1.79000     -12         -264      113
  2000 16860600.000000          3.60000       -1.30000       -2.40000       0.600000            148701.        3.40000             616.000              2.61000           492.000           125.000           20.5000            1.62000     -14         -155      109
  2000 16864200.000000          4.10000       -1.00000       -2.20000       0.500000            116372.        2.70000             614.000              2.20000           485.000           124.000           20.5000            1.73000     -20         -140       89
  2000 16867800.000000          4.30000       -1.40000       -1.00000       -3.60000            96452.0        2.50000             607.000              1.91000           465.000           119.000           19.5000            1.63000     -19         -275      240
#  
# Key Parameter and Survey data (labels K0,K1,K2) are preliminary browse data.
# Generated by CDAWeb on: Mon Nov 15 15:35:02 2021
```

suddenly throws a fit.

Interestingly, comments at the bottom of the file do not cause issues.

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Just to be sure, which OS are you using and what kind of line endings do you files have? LF or CRLF?

Comment: @Nullman python 3.7.5 on mac 11.2, and the .txt file has LF line endings and is UTF-8 encoding

Comment: Have you tried to `skip_header=3`?  I'm not sure which occurs first, skipping a header or skipping a comment line.  You might need to show the full traceback so we (and you) can see where the error occurs.

Comment: @hpaulj okay, so `skip_header=3` worked, and I guess it's just not considering the lines starting with # as commented. But then I am confused as to why the `comments='#'` parameter is not working.

Comment: It must be skipping header lines first, and then checking for comments after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a copy-n-paste of the problem sample:

```
In [328]: data=np.genfromtxt(txt, dtype=None, skip_header=3)
In [329]: data
Out[329]: 
array([(2000, 16849800., 5.5, -4.9, -0.8, -1.2, 321609., 2.8, 606., 1.92, 614., 156., 25.5, 1.87, -29, -279, 234),
       (2000, 16853400., 4.3, -2.9, -2.9,  0.4, 200127., 3.4, 611., 2.42, 625., 159., 26.2, 1.91, -20, -245, 164),
       (2000, 16857000., 3.9, -2.1, -2.5,  1.4, 174932., 3.7, 615., 2.7 , 549., 142., 23.2, 1.79, -12, -264, 113),
       (2000, 16860600., 3.6, -1.3, -2.4,  0.6, 148701., 3.4, 616., 2.61, 492., 125., 20.5, 1.62, -14, -155, 109),
       (2000, 16864200., 4.1, -1. , -2.2,  0.5, 116372., 2.7, 614., 2.2 , 485., 124., 20.5, 1.73, -20, -140,  89),
       (2000, 16867800., 4.3, -1.4, -1. , -3.6,  96452., 2.5, 607., 1.91, 465., 119., 19.5, 1.63, -19, -275, 240)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<f8'), ('f5', '<f8'), ('f6', '<f8'), ('f7', '<f8'), ('f8', '<f8'), ('f9', '<f8'), ('f10', '<f8'), ('f11', '<f8'), ('f12', '<f8'), ('f13', '<f8'), ('f14', '<i8'), ('f15', '<i8'), ('f16', '<i8')])
```

just skipping 2 lines:

```
In [330]: data=np.genfromtxt(txt, dtype=None, skip_header=2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-330-03af4b10cbea>", line 1, in <module>
    data=np.genfromtxt(txt, dtype=None, skip_header=2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 2124, in genfromtxt
    raise ValueError(errmsg)
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #4 (got 17 columns instead of 16)
    Line #5 (got 17 columns instead of 16)
    Line #6 (got 17 columns instead of 16)
    Line #7 (got 17 columns instead of 16)
    Line #8 (got 17 columns instead of 16)
    Line #9 (got 17 columns instead of 16)
```

With skip_header=2 it's trying to read the 3rd line (the comment detection must come later)

```
In [335]: data=np.genfromtxt(txt, dtype=None, skip_header=2, max_rows=1)
<ipython-input-335-83f145ee8d7c>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Reading unicode strings without specifying the encoding argument is deprecated. Set the encoding, use None for the system default.
  data=np.genfromtxt(txt, dtype=None, skip_header=2, max_rows=1)
In [336]: data
Out[336]: 
array([b'Year____Secs-of-year', b'nT', b'nT', b'nT', b'nT', b'Deg_K',
       b'Per_cc', b'Km/s', b'nPa', b'1/(SQcm-ster-s)', b'1/(SQcm-ster-s)',
       b'1/(SQcm-ster-s)', b'1/(SQcm-ster-s)', b'nT', b'nT', b'nT'],
      dtype='|S20')
```

and it only detects 16 fields here.  That messes up the field count for the other rows.

Comment: I see, so skip_header runs before comments. Thank you!